# wp_nav_menu count posts from custom post-type

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I am making a wordpress portfolio website.

I want to count my posts from a custom post-type in my menu.

This is what I want to achieve:

```
Designs  Films 
 15        20
```

This is the code that I have for my menu:

```
<?php
            if (get_sub_option(GN_SLUG, 'use_bootstrap', false)) {
                wp_nav_menu(array(
                    'menu' => 'top',
                    'theme_location' => 'top',
                    'depth' => 2,
                    'container' => 'div',
                    'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
                    'container_id' => 'navbar',
                    'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav navbarTop',
                    'fallback_cb' => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
                    'walker' => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())


                );
            }
            else {
                wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'top'));
            }
        ?>
```

I know how to count my custom post-type

```
$posts = get_posts('post_type= work_content');
$count = count($posts);
echo $count;
```

But I don't know how to combine the counter to my menu... Is this possible? How can I handle this?

Thanks!

Comment: Normaly I would achieve this with a [walker](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker), but you use already one.

Comment: @AndyTschiersch how do you add it in the walker?

Answer (score 0):

To give you an idea how could look such a Walker, here is an example:

```
class My_Walker_Nav_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {


    /**
     * Ends the element output, if needed.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @see Walker::end_el()
     *
     * @param string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
     * @param object $item   Page data object. Not used.
     * @param int    $depth  Depth of page. Not Used.
     * @param array  $args   An array of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
     */
    public function end_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {

        // var_dump( $item );

        $my_count_slugs = array('films', 'designs');

        if ( in_array( $item->post_name, $my_count_slugs ) ) {
            $count = get_count_from_your_counter_function( $item->post_name );
            $output .= '<div class="count">'. $count .'</div>';
        }

        $output .= "</li>\n";
    }

}
```

In your `wp_nav_menu()` you must use now `'walker' => new My_Walker_Nav_Menu`.

`get_count_from_your_counter_function()` should be return the counter value (you have to create this function).

Answer (score 0):

1) At first, you should ask WP question at [wordpress.stackexchange.com](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com)

2) about solution: you can do this :

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', function($menu) { 
    $GLOBALS['my_counter_fro_design']= substr_count($menu, 'menu-item-object-Designs');
    $GLOBALS['my_counter_fro_film']= substr_count($menu, 'menu-item-object-Films');
});
```

then , after executing the `wp_nav_menu` function, you can i.e.:

```
var_dump($GLOBALS['my_counter_fro_design']); exit;
```

Comment: When I tried this method, I get an "unable to reach site". 
I put the `add_filter ` in the `functions.php` and the `var_dump` after executing the nav...