# How can i add a notification badge on menu item in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I want to add a counter badge on the menu item that shows the number count of new posts for each time a new post is submitted. Like a facebook notification. Is there any plugin for that?

here is how the menu item looks like on my Wordpress site.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRABM.jpg][1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to modify the menu using nav_walker

[1] https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/100427/how-to-add-post-count-to-wp-nav-menu

[2] https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/88426/custom-nav-walker-menu-display-children-count

[3] [wp_nav_menu count posts from custom post-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39872692/wp-nav-menu-count-posts-from-custom-post-type)